# Port forwarding does not work (trying to make my computer an HTTP server)

Tags: port-forwarding, nat

**Goal**: Allow one person to connect remotely to my (Django) webserver which runs locally on my windows 10 machine, for a week or so.

**What I tried**: Disabled firewall (Windows), there seems to be no firewall on my router. I set up port forwarding on my router with ext. IP set to 0.0.0.0 and local IP set to my static PC IP.
It doesn't work, I guess the ISP has an additional box.

**Questions**: Is there any workaround that does not involve my ISP?

1. I guess there should be open ports that are accessible on my machine, because I do use Zoom and other software, right? Can I use one of those somehow?
2. Is it possible to create some sort of a VPN or a "tunnel" between the two computers so the other guy can connect to my PC?

Appreciate your help and thoughts.

**Solution**
Thanks to the answers below, seems like the free version of Ngrok is doing the trick.

Comment: Is the web server http or https? Which ports did you open up? 80? 8080? 443? Here is a huge list of routers with instructions how to set up port forwarding https://portforward.com/router.htm Do not install their software.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260727/how-to-access-the-local-django-webserver-from-outside-world

Comment: @Gantendo Thanks, I'm using HTTPS and opened up port 80.
I followed portforward.com before posting, and my configurations seems to be good and in accordance to their instructions. I'll try to follow the other link you posted.

Comment: Port 80 is for HTTP, not HTTPS. HTTPS uses 443 (and sometimes 8443 is used as an alternative).

Comment: Is HTTPS necessary? Using HTTP is probably easier. HTTPS requires a certificate which makes configuration a bit more complicated

Comment: @Gantendo No, I can live with HTTP as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess there should be open ports that are accessible on my machine, because I do use Zoom and other software, right?

Sort of, but not exactly.

First, ports are not symmetric; each end of a connection has its own port number. For example, an HTTP connection doesn't just go "over" port 80 – it goes to *the server's* port 80, while on your side there's a different (temporarily allocated) port number (e.g. mypc:24567 → zoom.com:80). So being able to make outbound connections to port 80 on the remote side does *not* mean you'll automatically be able to accept inbound ones to port 80 on your side.

More importantly, when you're behind a NAT and connect outbound, the router makes *temporary* port assignments that only last for as long as the individual connection does (and often, only match packets *from* the specific remote IP:port that you're talking to).

For example, when you connect to one of Zoom's servers from 192.168.1.99:24680 to ZoomServer:443, the router tracks a temporary 'port forwarding' state mapping some external port to 192.168.1.99:24680, but it is forgotten as soon as the router sees the TCP connection being closed.

Some VoIP software like Zoom may use outbound connections exclusively, relaying everything through their servers for privacy reasons. Other programs try to connect participants peer-to-peer – typically they still need a central "meeting point" server so that both peers could cooperate and trick their NATs into allowing a connection through.

> Is it possible to create some sort of a VPN or a "tunnel" between the two computers so the other guy can connect to my PC?

Yes, as long as *one* of the parties involved can receive inbound connections to establish the tunnel. This doesn't need to be the "other guy" directly; it could be a 3rd VPN server acting as a hub which both people connect to. (I mean a personal VPN that you'd set up on your own server – not commercial VPN services; those are likely to block internal communications for security reasons.)

The "TCP forwarding" feature in SSH can also be used easily – the `-R` option (remote tunnel) would accept connections at the SSH server and tunnel them to your local machine. This is most useful when you have root rights on the server and can enable 'GatewayPorts' in its sshd_config, as this would allow the other person to directly connect to the server's tunnel port, without them needing to use SSH at all.

There are also special-purpose tunnel services (e.g. [Ngrok/Serveo/Localtunnel/Pagekite](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/anderspitman-awesome-tunneling-python-networking-programming)) that do this specifically for HTTP/HTTPS.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the elaborated answer. Can you link to a tutorial on opening such tunnel between the two machines? (my machine is windows 10, with admin privilege)
Or what to search in google, as I'm really not familiar with any of these. Thanks

Comment: I'm trying the free version of Ngrok, it seems to solve my issue. Thanks again